# Java - Rule-based sorting using bellman-held-karp algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I asked the following question on CS SE, and have no idea as to how to implement the answer in java (let alone make out what it is actually saying):

I am trying to plant a row in a garden. Certain plants are good for some plants and bad for others, and I am trying to find the best order of plants: most adjacent friends and no adjacent foes, as defined in this table (I have one of each):

```
Num Vegetable     Friends      Foes
1   Watermelon    7,4,3        8,6
2   Tomatoes      9,8,6,5,1    7
3   Sunflowers    7,6,11  
4   Zucchini      9,7,3   
5   Eggplant      9,6,2        7,10
6   Cucumbers     9,7,3        8,1
7   Corn          8,6,4,3,1    5,2
8   Cantaloup     7,4,3        6,1
9   Bell peppers  6,5,11,10,2 
10  Swiss chard   2            5
11  Rhubarb       9,3
```

How do I find the arrangement?

"Jakube" answered:

> You can solve such a problem by simply iterating over all n! different
> permutations, and checking each if any of the arrangements is allowed
> and how good it is. This has complexity O(n⋅n!).
>
> Much faster (but still exponential complexity) will be a variation to
> the Bellman–Held–Karp algorithm. Compute for each pair (V,v) with V
> being a subset of all vegetables and and v∈V, if it is possible to
> arrange the vegetables V in a way such that v is the last one and what
> it's best value is. You can define a recursive formula for this
> function, and apply dynamic programming, like in the BHK algorithm.
> That should run in O(n<sup>2</sup>⋅2n)."

I originally asked the question for a case where I had one of each, but now realize that I need an answer which can take more an occasional duplicate. I am not sure if the answer he gave is applicable to a case where I have more than one of a given plant.

Comment: Is a watermelon a friend of a watermelon?  If you can have duplicates, the fastest solution would be to plant one vegetable multiple times.  A normal constraint is that you have to plant at least one of all the vegetables.  If you plant one of each vegetable and plant all the vegetables, then @jakube's first paragraph applies.  In other words, what are the actual constraints of the solution?

Comment: Also, I think, there is no "best" arrangement.  A watermelon next to a corn plant is just as valid as a cantaloupe next to a sunflower plant.  The first solution that meets the constraints you've defined would be as good as any other arrangement.  What are the actual constraints of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you tagged this Java, but here's some Python implementing that dynamic program.

```
import collections

Plant = collections.namedtuple("Plant", ("id", "name", "friends", "foes"))


def extend(first_plant, result):
    objective, other_plants = result
    return (
        (first_plant.id in other_plants[0].friends)
        + (other_plants[0].id in first_plant.friends)
        + objective,
        [first_plant] + other_plants,
    )


def best_order_recursive(first_plant, other_plants, cache):
    if not other_plants:
        return 0, [first_plant]
    cache_key = (first_plant.id, frozenset(plant.id for plant in other_plants))
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}
    else:
        cache_value = cache.get(cache_key)
        if cache_value is not None:
            return cache_value
    value = max(
        (
            extend(
                first_plant,
                best_order_recursive(
                    next_plant, other_plants[:i] + other_plants[i + 1 :], cache
                ),
            )
            for (i, next_plant) in enumerate(other_plants)
            if first_plant.id not in next_plant.foes
            and next_plant.id not in first_plant.foes
        ),
        default=(float("-inf"), [first_plant]),
    )
    cache[cache_key] = value
    return value


def best_order(plants):
    cache = {}
    return max(
        best_order_recursive(first_plant, plants[:i] + plants[i + 1 :], cache)
        for (i, first_plant) in enumerate(plants)
    )


def main():
    objective, plants = best_order(
        [
            Plant(1, "Watermelon", {7, 4, 3}, {8, 6}),
            Plant(2, "Tomatoes", {9, 8, 6, 5, 1}, {7}),
            Plant(3, "Sunflowers", {7, 6, 11}, set()),
            Plant(4, "Zucchini", {9, 7, 3}, set()),
            Plant(5, "Eggplant", {9, 6, 2}, {7, 10}),
            Plant(6, "Cucumbers", {9, 7, 3}, {8, 1}),
            Plant(7, "Corn", {8, 6, 4, 3, 1}, {5, 2}),
            Plant(8, "Cantaloupe", {7, 4, 3}, {6, 1}),
            Plant(9, "Bell peppers", {6, 5, 11, 10, 2}, set()),
            Plant(10, "Swiss chard", {2}, {5}),
            Plant(11, "Rhubarb", {9, 3}, set()),
        ]
    )
    print(objective)
    print(*(plant.name for plant in plants), sep=", ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The computation was instantaneous! The result: "17
Swiss chard, Tomatoes, Eggplant, Bell peppers, Rhubarb, Sunflowers, Cucumbers, Corn, Cantaloupe, Zucchini, Watermelon" What does the number mean?

Comment: @Sam number of times a plant has a friend on the left plus number of times a plant has a friend on the right.

Comment: That dodesn't at all take into account foes... Also,I ran this configuration using a brute-force algorth and ddidn't ger a single result greater than 10...?

Comment: @Sam No adjacent foe relationships are allowed. The reason the score is >10 here is that we're counting some adjacent pairs twice -- for example, if we just had watermelon next to corn, that would score 2 here (and presumably 1 in your brute force algorithm). If we did bell peppers next to Swiss chard, then that would score only 1 since Swiss chard is bell peppers' friend, but bell peppers aren't Swiss chard's friend. Unclear if that was a data entry oversight.

Comment: I just encountered an almost identitcal problem, but with two small changes: I have to plant the plants in an oval, such that the plants loop on themselves, like so:
 -------<br/>
-_____-
and all relationships are mutual, so each relationship should only count once. How would the code change? Should I ask this as a seperate question? I wrote the points calculation func in Kotlin like so
fun calcPoints(a: Int, b: Int): Int {return when {
b in listOfFoes[a] || a in listOfFoes[b] -> -1 b in listOfFriends[a] || a in listOfFriends[b] -> 1 else -> 0} and the loop to compare the pairs incremnts.

Comment: @Sam Not too difficult. We add an argument to `best_order_recursive` to remember the very first plant chosen (pass `first_plant` to it in `best_order` and just pass it down through the recursive calls). When `other_plants` is empty, we know that `first_plant` (actually the last plant at this point) loops back on the very first plant, so we need to enforce foe relationships and count friends instead of just returning `0`.